# If true, proceed with script

Tags: powershell

Trying to perform an if/else statement to an existing test lab machine configuration script. Basically I want to search for an exact file path, if it is true proceed with script, if false, stop script and display driver name and version.

I've tried with the continue statement, but powershell doesn't like it

```
Function Namespace_Check
{    Write-Host "Checking available namepace" -ForegroundColor Green
     Get-CimInstance -namespace "root\cimv2" -ClassName __NAMESPACE
     $path = "root\cimv2\NV"
     Write-Host "Complete" -ForegroundColor Green

     if 
        ($path -match '*NV*' ){continue}

     else
        {Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, driverversion | where {$_.devicename -like "*nvidia*"}}     

}
```

I would like for when the "if" statement is true, to continue running remaining script and when the "if" statement is false, to stop the script and display the driver name and version to display similar to this:

```
Product Name        : Quadro P2000
Video Driver Version: 391.03
```

Comment: Put the code you want to run in the if statement and use `exit` in the `else` after printing your wanted information

Comment: Thanks for the edit, was trying to figure out why it wasn't displaying properly.

Comment: use `return` to keep going outside the function

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your `$path` variable, if your purpose is to check If the namespace contains the 'NV' you can do:

```
if ((Get-CimInstance -namespace "root\cimv2" -ClassName __NAMESPACE).Name -match 'NV')
{
return
}

else {
return (Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, driverversion | where {$_.devicename -like "*nvidia*"})
}
```

anyway using your code, you can update it to:

```
Function Namespace_Check
{    Write-Host "Checking available namepace" -ForegroundColor Green
     Get-CimInstance -namespace "root\cimv2" -ClassName __NAMESPACE
     $path = "root\cimv2\NV"
     Write-Host "Complete" -ForegroundColor Green

     if 
        ($path -match '*NV*' ){return}

     else
        { return (Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, driverversion | where {$_.devicename -like "*nvidia*"}})     

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I took your advice, it's cleaner. Now my next question is, during the "else" statement. I want it to run the "Get-WmiObject" cmdlet and give me a report of the current driver and version, write a statement, and stop the script without closing the window. I've tried a couple things to no avail, can you help?